# User Defined PDF Templates in Laravel 6

Tags: php, html, laravel, templates, pdf

Currently building a system that requires users to design a custom template for a PDF document generated by the application. To achieve this, I have saved a blade template in the database to be retrieved when the document is about to be converted into a PDF document.

I know Laravel's View component can pick up a blade template from the file system and render it as an HTML document. However, to achieve my objective, this component should be able to read a text field fetched from the database. This is not currently possible with Laravel and I suspect is largely due to security reasons.

The question now is, how else can this be achieved using Laravel or what may be the recommended way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and re-reading your initial question, my best guess is that you need a macro replacement function.  This is the method I use for email templates in my own applications, which are stored in the database.  It sounds similar to what you are attempting to do.

**Helpers.php**
Some autoloaded helpers file.

```php
if (!function_exists('macro_parse')) {
    function macro_parse($body, $haystack, $pattern = '/{{([^}]+)}}/')
    {
        $replace = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($needle) use ($haystack) {
            return $haystack[$needle[1]];
        }, $body);

        return $replace;
    }
} else {
    Log::error("macro_parse is already defined");
}
```

**Usage**

```php
// a simple template example...
// you would retrieve this template from the database
$template = '<div>{{some_macro}}</div>';

// key/value pairs can be set from database values
$macros = [
    'some_macro' => 'it works!'
];

// parse the template
$parsed = macro_parse($template,$macros);


dd($parsed); // <div>it works!</div>
```

You can then pass the filled template to the PDF generator.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear in my question but what I meant was fetching the content of the template itself from the database, passing it to the view along with the data. There wouldn't be any `pdf-template.blade.php`

Comment: Please show your code.  It might help me to better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have updated my answer to my best guess as to what you are attempting.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is close to what I was asking for. But what about parsing collections like `{{ $post-comments }}` or using `{% if(...) %}` or `{% foreach(...) %}`?

Comment: You could write custom HTML snippets to handle collections. A simple macro parse can't handle if statements. You would likely need to write your own template parser as I'm not aware of any packages that can do this for you. You are correct that exposing blade code (or any code that allows users to run custom PHP) would pose a major security risk.